# Date localization in Angular

Tags: angular, date, internationalization, ngx-translate, date-pipe

In my Angular 8 app, I can't manage to display date fields in a localized form. I'd like to come up with something like the following:

- in English : "February 18, 2020 12:15:50"
- in French : "18 février 2020, 12:15:50"

I guess I should use Angular's `DatePipe`:

> {{ myDate | date }}

For all other localization purposes, I am using `ngx-translate` (not `Angular i18n`). It gives me access to the current language (the user can switch language on the fly), but I don't know how I can link `TranslateService#currentLang` with the language used in the `DatePipe`. Is there a way to do so in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

angular provides a lot of locales, so use can register right locale which will be used in date pipe.

```
// app.module.ts

import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import frenchLocale from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

registerLocaleData(frenchLocale);
```

Then you can specify locale in date pipe

```
someDate | date: null: null: 'fr'
```

or overried default locale

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "fr" }
  ]
})
```

**UPDATE**

Angular i18n uses differential builds, but ngx-translate fetches needed locale on demand. As we can not combine those approaches, we can create custom date pipe, which would meet our requirements.

I created [demo](http://stackblitz.com/github/shumih/async-date-app) with current TranslateService locale provider and custom date pipe which reactive equivalent of original date.pipe

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. However, how can I avoid to hard-code ```'en'``` in ```someDate | date: null: null: 'en'``` and instead put "the current language"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe). As you can see, it use `LOCALE_ID` token be default. If you use Angular CLI, LOCALE_ID is provided automatically:

> A locale code for the locale format rules to use. When not supplied,
>   uses the value of LOCALE_ID, which is en-US by default